# If group contains a value, change all items in column to value

Tags: sql, excel, grouping, calculated-columns, dax

Anyone know how I can add a column that changes all the Type entries to 'New' if the client at anytime had 'New'?

example:

```
Trans  Date   Client Type
0001  1/2/13   1234  New
0002  1/4/13   1234  Returning
0003  1/3/13   1234  Returning
0004  1/3/13   1234  Returning
0005  1/5/13   1234  Returning
```

I would like to do this in DAX but Excel or SQL work too. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Try this.

```
UPDATE Table 
SET Type = 'New'
WHERE Client IN (SELECT DISTINCT Client FROM Table WHERE Type = 'New')
```

I do not know why I was down voted but here is a [SQLFIDDLE](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/1210c/1) that shows that the query does work.

Comment: Do you have an excel solution too?

Comment: No I do not have an Excel solution.

Answer (score 0):

I have a two column solution for you. Look at formulae in columns E and F. References assume your data is in columns A-D starting at row 2, alter as necessary. You could also do an array formula of this if yo really want the one column solution

```
      A     B       C      D         
1   Trans  Date   Client Type        
2   0001  1/2/13   1234  New         
3   0002  1/4/13   1234  Returning
4   0003  1/3/13   1234  Returning
5   0004  1/3/13   1234  Returning
6   0005  1/5/13   1234  Returning
```

In column E - Concatonate your client number and type:

```
"=C2&D2".
```

This will yield results such as 1234New, 1234Returning etc.

In column F - Test to see if anything in column E has the row client number + "New". If there is anything that has that client number and new in column E, return "New" as the status otherwise return existing status:

```
"=IF(COUNTIF($E$2:$E$6,C2&"New")>=1,"New",D2)"
```